# Existe como adicionar atributo dinamicamente em objeto instanciado no C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, mvvm, prism

Bom, no C# colocamos atributos da seguinte forma:

```
[Required("Este campo é obrigatório")]
public string Nome {get; set;}
```

O que eu gostaria de saber, é se existe uma forma de adicionar atributos de forma dinâmica à objetos instanciados. Como o código hipotético seguinte:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.Nome.AdicionarAtributo(Required());
```

**Contexto**

O contexto é o seguinte: estou criando um projeto Universal Windows, usando Prism e aplicando MVVM. Porém para cada campo de um modelo eu estou criando um campo na ViewModel, depois, no método Save(), eu crio uma instância do modelo e atribuo os valores da ViewModel. Os atributos, no momento, estão nos campos da ViewModel, mas eu queria fazer algo diferente. Minha ViewModel ficaria basicamente desta forma:

```
public class ClienteViewModel: ValidatableBindableBase
{
    private Cliente _modelo;

    public Cliente Modelo
    {
        get => _modelo;
        set => SetProperty(ref _modelo, value);
    }
    public ClienteViewModel()
    {
        Modelo.Campo.AdicionarAtributo(Required());
        [...]
    }

    [...]
    public void Salvar()
    {
        if(ValidateProperties()){
            _serviço.Salvar(_modelo);
        }
    }
}
```

Meu objetivo é despoluir minha ViewModel, se alguém souber uma forma ainda melhor de fazer isso, será muito bem vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao objeto instanciado não pode, atributos existem em tipos e seus membros, não em instâncias. Geralmente é o que precisa, e quase sempre não tem motivo para colocar dinamicamente, dá mais trabalho, tem mais chances de algo dar errado sem um ganho real.

Na verdade nem costuma fazer sentido o que pretende. E se fizer para seu caso deveria usar uma linguagem dinâmica e não C#. Eu acho que está poluindo um tipo, não o oposto.

Se acha que está fazendo muito trabalho braçal, dou as boas vindas ao mundo das arquiteturas complexas. Ou começa fazer arquiteturas mais simples ou conviva com isto.

Talvez, uma solução melhor seria criar um gerador de código. Em alguns casos é bem adequado.

Comment: Trabalho braçal nem seria tanto o problema, na verdade me preocupa mais o código ficando feio e poluído haha. Fiz algumas pesquisas e vi algo sobre pôr um objeto entre a model e a ViewModel, e neste objeto as propriedades e atributos que pretendo, deixando basicamente a viewmodel cuidar apenas dos comandos... acha que isso isso é válido? Ou é só ainda mais trabalho pra pouco retorno?

Comment: Precisaria ver em detalhes, mas Viewmodel deveria ser super simples, só com as propriedades

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não tentei fazer isto, vi gente dizendo que não é possível, mas [alguns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-property-at-runtime/) dizendo que é possível :)

Existe o

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object, Attribute[])
```

Tem também este exemplo com o [FastDeepCloner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/)

```
public class test{
public string Name{ get; set; }
}

var prop = now DeepCloner.GetFastDeepClonerProperties(typeof(test)).First();
prop.Attributes.Add(new JsonIgnoreAttribute());
// now test and se if exist 
prop = now DeepCloner.GetFastDeepClonerProperties(typeof(test)).First();
bool containAttr = prop.ContainAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>()
// or 
JsonIgnoreAttribute myAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256356/194717

Answer (score 1):

Para despoluir a ViewModel, vou dar a dica do NuGet [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

```
public class ClienteViewModel: ValidatableBindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Cliente Modelo {get; set;}

    public ClienteViewModel()
    {
        Modelo.Campo.AdicionarAtributo(Required());
        [...]
    }

    [...]
    public void Salvar()
    {
        if(ValidateProperties()){
            _serviço.Salvar(Modelo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu Tony, mas o Prism já implementa essa interface no método SetProperty(); A outra solução é como por correntes nas rodas, acabaria me dando mais trabalho, mas valeu por me mostrar que isso é possível.